# improve complex query in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I would like to know how to get all the rows from table1 that have a matching row in table3.

Teh structure of the tables is:

```
table1:
k1 k2

table2:
k1 k2 t1 t2 date type

table3:
t1 t2 date status
```

The conditions are:

- k1 and k2 have to match with the corresponding columns in table2.
- In table2 I will only chek those rows where date='today' and type='a'.
- That can return 0, 1 or many rows in table2.
- Looking at t1 and t2 from table 2, I get the rows that match in table3.
- If in table3 date='today' and status='ok', I will return the original row from table1, this is, k1 and k2.

How can I do this query (inner joins, exists, whatever) having into account that the three tables have millions of rows, so it must be as optimal as possible?

I have the query, which is right for sure, but they are too many conditions for Teradata to come with the answer. Too many joins, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider three tables and a few millions of rows a complex query.

In Teradata you usually don't have to think that much about join/in/exists, all will be rewritten to joins internally. But there's is a one-to-many-to-one relation, so you should avoid a join as this will need a final DISTINCT.

Better use IN or EXISTS instead:

```
SELECT
    K1,K2
FROM Table1
WHERE (K1,K2) IN
 ( 
   SELECT K1,K2
   FROM Table2 
   WHERE datecol = CURRENT_DATE
     AND typecol = 'a'
     AND (T1,T2) IN
      (
        SELECT T1,T2
        FROM Table3
        WHERE datecol = CURRENT_DATE
        AND status = 'ok'
      )
 )
```

Regarding the actual plan: if there are the necessary statistics the optimizer should choose a good plan, check the confidences levels in Explain. You can also run a `diagnostic helpstats on for session;` before running Explain to see if there are missing stats.

Comment: Your example is with IN. Wouldn't it be better to use EXISTS? What should I SELECT in the subquery to make it optimal for an EXISTS? SELECT *? SELECT 1?

Comment: There should be the same plan for both IN and EXISTS (only NOT IN might be much worse than NOT EXISTS), but you might simply try it. Every decent optimizer will show no difference between `SELECT *`, `SELECT 1` or `SELECT column` within EXISTS.

Comment: Is Teradata SQL Assistant a "decent optimizer", then?

Comment: SQL Assistant is just a client, but Teradata has a quite smart optimizer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work.

```
SELECT
    Table1.*
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON
        Table1.K1 = Table2.K1 AND
        Table1.K2 = Table2.K2 AND
        Table2.date = CURRENT_DATE and
        Table2.type = 'a'
    INNER JOIN Table3 ON
        Table2.T1 = Table3.T1 AND
        Table2.T2 = Table3.T2 AND
        Table3.date = CURRENT_DATE and
        Table3.status = "OK"
```

### Update:

Speaking more to the optimization part of the question. The execution steps that Teradata will most likely take here are:

1. In parallel it will select all records from `Table1`, Records from `Table2` where the `date` is `CURRENT_DATE` and the `type` is `a`, and Records from Table3 where the `date` is `CURRENT_DATE` and the `status` is `OK`.
2. It will then join the results from the `SELECT` of `Table2` to the results of the `SELECT` from `table1`.
3. It will then join the results from that to the results from the `SELECT` of `table3`.

You can get more information by putting `EXPLAIN` before your SELECT query. The results returned from the database will be the explanation of your Teradata server will execute the query, which can be very enlightening when trying to optimize a big slow query.

Unfortunately the steps above are the best you can hope for. Parallel execution of all three tables with the filters applied, and then a join of the results. With big data, the slowest part of a query is often the join, so filtering before you get to that step is a big plus.

There's more that can be done to optimize like making sure your Indexes are in order and Collecting statistics, especially on fields where you will be filtering. But without the admin access to do that, your hands are tied.

Comment: The problem is not the SQL, I have tried that, but it's not good enough. About the optimization of the database: I do not administrate it. So I can only make a more efficient query that avoids joining all three tables and later, for example, deleting most of the rows because the status is not "OK" but only after joing and joining millions of rows (I think that's how the inner join works).

Comment: Unfortunately without admin ability to mess with the tables a bit, your hands are a bit tied. I've explained more about how Teradata will most likely process the above request in the most recent answer edit.

Comment: "With big data, the slowest part of a query is often the join, so filtering before you get to that step is a big plus.": how can I get that?

Comment: "making sure your Indexes are in order and Collecting statistics": I can only acess the database, I do not administer it.